# Java Regex Lookbehind and Lookahead

Tags: java, regex

I want to create a regex that can identify equals signs in a string. The only condition is the equals sign can't be preceded with these characters: '<', '>', '~' and '='. It also can't be followed by this character '='. The regex statement I used was this: `(?<=[^<>~=])=(?=[^=])` and works for the most part. How can I modify this regex so that it also matches equal signs that are either preceded by nothing or followed by nothing.

For example, all these strings should match: `hello=45`, `3=dkfjasdkf`, `=3`, `ten=` and even just `=`.

It shouldn't match: `hello==4`, `3>=4`, and `==`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use negative look-arounds to allow matches to occur at the start or end of the string.

```
(?<![<>~=])=(?!=)
```